# Is it possible to import a Shapefile from Manifold into QGIS with the same projection?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, manifold

is it possible to import a shapefiles from manifold to Qgis with the same projection?

Comment: What file extensions do your source files have? Shapefiles usually come as a bunch of files.

Comment: the shapefiles extensions from manifod are *.dbf, *.prj, *.shp and *.shx..

Comment: So the projection information should be in the .prj file. You can look into it with any text editor. Does QGIS prompt you for a CRS, or assigns a wrong one?

Answer (score 2):

Shapefiles don't have projection metadata, they were designed only for use with longitude/latitude data - though many systems recognize an auxiliary .prj with WKT. Manifold forces you to export the .prj manually - but still you must make sure your drawing does not have a local scale or offset values, since WKT can't represent that.

Try it with Mapinfo format which is a vastly better format anyway. It's known as MIF, with .mif/.mid extension for the two files.

(Manifold does not yet support GeoPackage which I would otherwise recommend).

http://www.georeference.org/doc/exporting_drawings.htm

Better options also exist to transfer data via a shared database.

If you still have problems with MIF I'm happy to help find a way that works, there's lots of other options.

Comment: I am not familiar with Manifold system and I really need a help. thank you

Comment: Can you post up the .xml that Manifold exports with the .mif?  That's the very least thing needed to test the workflow, of export to MIF, and opening in QGIS, and checking it.

Comment: Hi... i try to export Manifold .prj to .shp and .mif... and then i add it as vector layer to Qgis and it works... but the scale of the project is different from the other vector layer that i need to transfer... is there any way for me to change the scale of a project of a manifold.? thanks :)

Comment: Before export, use Edit Projection to set the local scales to 1 and local offsets to 0. (Don't user Assign Projection to do that).

Comment: who to edit projection.? which of these, can edit projection? change projection.../ assign projection / or at the properties...

Comment: Sorry, Change Projection (not Edit). Showing my age

Comment: thanks it works.. now may only problem is how to move my new vector layer to the other layers... thank you .. :)

Answer (score 1):

QGIS can open shapefiles natively.  So, as long as the projection is stored with the shapefile, you should have no trouble opening it in QGIS.

Go to Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer

[image]

Select your shapefile.